# How to use exception in my executionStatement

Tags: java

I have this exception and I would like to use it in my executeStatement. How do i do so?

```
package cn.edu.thssdb.parser;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.BaseErrorListener;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.RecognitionException;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.Recognizer;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.ParseCancellationException;

public class ThrowingErrorListener extends BaseErrorListener {

    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e)
            throws ParseCancellationException {
        throw new ParseCancellationException("line " + line + ":" + charPositionInLine + " " + msg + '\n');
    }
}
```

```
private static void executeStatement(String stmt, long sessionid) {
    ExecuteStatementReq req = new ExecuteStatementReq();
    req.setSessionId(sessionid);
    req.setStatement(stmt);
    try {
      ExecuteStatementResp resp = client.executeStatement(req);
      println(resp.getResult());
    } catch (TException e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Also, can i use it with TException or just replace it with my ThrowingErrorListener?

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to use it in my executeStatement.". Do you mean you'd like to throw that exception if a TException happens?

Comment: @fpezzini Yes sorry for the bad english

Comment: Sure, so first of all you either need to make that method syntaxError static or you need an instance of ThrowingErrorListener. Assuming you make it static, the you could call the method with ThrowingErrorListener.syntaxError(... parameters here...).